# Access SQL query. 3 date reoccurences in seven days on an id

Tags: sql, ms-access

Anyones help on this would be very much appreciated..

I have a Table with lots of fields but the two I want to query is

'MachineId' <- Id Field

'DateLogged' <- Date and time Service Call Logged

The MachineId represents a physical machine onsite. What i'm after is, has the machine had 3 calls logged to it within 7 days. Not just in the last seven days but in the lifetime of the machine.

I wanted to return a table with the MachineId's that hit this criteria.

I'm banging my head. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a self-join and aggregation.  The idea is to find any matching record within a week after each row in the table.  Then aggregate by the original row and count the number of matches:

```
select t.MachineId, t.DateLogged, count(*) as NumIncidents
from table t inner join
     table t2
     on t.MachineId = t2.MachineId and
        t2.DateLogged between t.DateLogged and dateadd("d", 6, t.DateLogged)
group by t.MachineId, t.DateLogged
having count(*) >= 3;
```